# Firebase Authentication and API access in Flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter, access-token

Currently, I have following things:

1. API server which was written by using Asp.Net Core 2.1.
2. Mobile app which was written by using flutter.
3. Firebase Authentication which is used to authenticate user (allow Email, Gmail and Facebook login).

The situation is like this, I want to secure API, only authorized user can call the API service, so I have to configure API server to add authorization in startup.cs like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/xxxxxxx";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/xxxxxx",
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = "xxxxxx",
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                };
            });
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
         app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

After that use [Authorize] attribute in controller to allow only authorized user can call the API. That all for my API configuration part.

In mobile app client, I am using [firebase_auth](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth), [google_sign_in](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in) and [flutter_facebook_login](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login) packages to perform google, facebook sign in.

Let say I use Firebase Auth with Facebook provider, my code is as follow:

```
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
    final FacebookLogin facebookSignIn = new FacebookLogin();

    Future _testFacebookLogin() async {
        final FacebookLoginResult result = await facebookSignIn.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']);

        switch (result.status) {
          case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
            final FacebookAccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken;
            final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithFacebook(accessToken: accessToken.token);
            assert(user.email != null);
            final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
            assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
            //Perform API call here?
            break;
          case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:

            break;
          case FacebookLoginStatus.error:

            break;
        }
    }
```

I am able to signed in and get the access token from Facebook. I passed the access token into Firebase Auth, and the user is able be registered in under Firebase.

**My Questions**

1. Will Firebase return me an access token and refresh token? I cant' find any access token was stored in currentUser variable.
2. After user authenticated, what access token (Facebook or Firebase) I should inject into authorization header in order to call my API?

Comment: firebase does return the token, check this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login) here, and you should put firebase access token in your authorization header